# How to test if Dojo/Javascript tree lazy loading is working?

Tags: javascript, dojo, tree, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I have a Dojo tree already in my code and I want to make the tree lazy loading for performance issues. I was using a ItemFileWriteStore that connected to a REST service that I made in Java. To implement the lazy load, I switched it to a JsonRestStore and added the deferItemLoadingUntilExpanded property to the tree model.

My question is, how do I test or make sure that the data is being loaded lazily?

Thanks

Comment: I am using firebug, but I am new to both, so if firebug has the capability, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you look at it in FireBug, Chrome dev tools, or a debugging proxy (Fiddler or similiar). 
That should show if the data is 1) present initially, and 2) http requests to load the rest when requred by lazy loading.

Comment: How would I know if data is present initially in firebug?

Comment: You don't want the data initally present, correct? You can use FireBug to explore the java script objects that have been created. You should be able to see the DOM tree structure, and verify that child nodes have not been fully created or populated. After you expand nodes the DOM should be different (the areas expanded should populated).

Comment: If you don't feel like poking around the the DOM or JavaScript heap in FireBug you can use something like Fiddler to verify that HTTP GETs are resulting from you expanding tree nodes (not just when loading the whole page). You can even use WireShark for that. And if you really just need a quick and dirty test load the page with the tree then kill your web server or disconnect from the network (if on a different box from the server). The lazy nodes won't load since they can't connect to the service.

Comment: To clarify - to view the DOM structure in Firebug click 'DOM' in the bar that starts just under the cockroach. The buttons read, Console, HTML, CSS, DOM, Net. You could click DOM to explore the DOM or leave the Net one open to see if network traffic results in you expanding a lazily loaded Node.

Comment: Some links to get you started debugging async HTTP requests (e.g ones that happen after the page initially loads, and before another page is loaded): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M and http://getfirebug.com/network (see the XmlHTTPRequest section at the bottom)

Comment: Well your way seems good, but the problem is, I don't have lazy loading of my tree implemented yet :/ ...When I get it working, I will come back and accept your answer.